# Sencha Architect, Touch application navigation very slow

Tags: extjs, navigation, touch

I'm pretty much brand new to Sencha and I'm working on building my first app.  I've been able to get setup an initial page and 6 form pages that 6 buttons will link too.  Everything runs fine when running in the browser in Preview mode but when deploying the app to my iPad 3 the navigation is very slow.  I don't even know what files to print out here in order to seek out help.  If anyone can respond I can update the post with whatever information is needed to resolve this.  Any help is much appreciated, I have been on google and SO for about an hour trying different things and nothing has helped (or it just made it worse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue was related to the image sizes.  Instead of using icons that were the exact sizes I was using what was originally sent to me which was about 1000% larger.